# Flutter: The behavior when executed on an actual iphone device has changed due to a smartphone model change

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter

I'm making an app with Flutter and testing it on an actual iPhone device.

I was using an iPhone 6S, but it broke yesterday, so I changed the model and purchased an iPhone SE.
When running the Flutter app on the actual device, with the previous iPhone 6S,
even if I removed the wire after testing the app, the app would take about a week from there I was able to use the app.

However, with the new iPhone SE, the app can be run only when the macbook and iPhone SE are connected with a wire, but if the wire is removed, the app cannot be started.
If possible, I would like to be able to run the app on the iPhone SE for about a week as before, without wires.
Is there any setting?

Comment: you need to add --profile mode when you run the app https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I used the green triangle (Run) button on the iPhone 6S, and after that I was able to use the app on my device for about a week. Do I need to use Profile mode on the iPhone SE?

Comment: yes you need profile mode to run device without wired, flutter run --profile here's the reference it's happen since iOS14 https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ios-14#launching-debug-flutter-without-a-host-computer

Comment: I was able to do it as I was told.
Thank you very much for telling me various things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to add --profile mode.
In other words
flutter run --profile
If I execute the above command, I will be able to run the app on my smartphone for about a week.